# Kibana elastic search regex string length

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, kibana, elastic-stack

I am trying to use the filter in discover tab for a field. I want to filter it by a regular expression like *abc****. I need to filter the table to check if a column contains a word with the pattern that start with "abc" or "ABC" and continues to have combination of 4 other characters(small lr capitals) or numbers.

Examples "abcnk12","ABC09PL","abc0978". First 3 letters are constant.

Can anyone please suggest how to write the regular expression like this or if there is any other way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Kibana regular expressions do not support `^` and `$` anchors since they are implicitly implied (full matches are always done), but I have included these anchors in the Regex Demo below, where they are required. Also, the following regex would not require specifying the case-insensitive flag:

```
(abc|ABC)[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AOjh9I/2/)

If other arbitrary characters may follow these first 7 characters, then we need to add `.*` at the end:

```
(abc|ABC)[a-zA-Z0-9]{4}.*
```

See: [Regexp query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-regexp-query.html)

If you specify `case-insensitive=true`, then the regex can be simplified to:

```
abc[a-z0-9]{4}
```

But be aware that values such as `aBcxxxx` will be accepted.

Comment: Getting the regex is not so hard (to search in google, at least), but to get it done in Kibana is little tricky I guess. I couldn't get an idea how to do that in kibana, yet.

Comment: @smilyface I've done some research on Kibana and have updated the regex based on my understanding.